# Awk if condition error

Tags: awk, syntax

I have written an awk command which filters based on a condition

```
awk '{if(( (substr($0,9,3) == "TGO") &&  ((substr($0,1,4) == "9123" || (substr($0,1,4) == "9704"))) print (substr($0,279,2),substr($0,1,4),substr($0,5,8));}' Downloadfinance.txt
```

This is a throwing a syntax error . I tried multiple ways but still it is throwing the same exception .

Here is the error

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {if(( (substr($0,9,3) == "TGO") &&  ((substr($0,1,4) == "9123" || (substr($0,1,4) == "9704"))) print (substr($0,9,3),substr($0,1,4),substr($0,5,8));}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                 ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {if(( (substr($0,9,3) == "TGO") &&  ((substr($0,1,4) == "9123" || (substr($0,1,4) == "9704"))) print (substr($0,9,3),substr($0,1,4),substr($0,5,8));}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                                                                       ^ syntax error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing two `)`, alternatively one `)` and then have one `(` too many.

Corrected code (with superfluous parentheses removed; newlines here are for illustration only, this won't actually run):

```c
{
        if (
                substr($0,9,3) == "TGO" &&
                (
                        substr($0,1,4) == "9123" || substr($0,1,4) == "9704"
                )
        )
                print substr($0,279,2), substr($0,1,4), substr($0,5,8)
}
```

or (this syntax is correct with regards to where the newlines are located)

```c
{
        if (substr($0,9,3) == "TGO" && (substr($0,1,4) == "9123" || substr($0,1,4) == "9704" ))
                print substr($0,279,2), substr($0,1,4), substr($0,5,8)
}
```

or (using the pattern-action mechanics)

```c
substr($0,9,3) == "TGO" && (substr($0,1,4) == "9123" || substr($0,1,4) == "9704") {
        print substr($0,279,2), substr($0,1,4), substr($0,5,8)
}
```

Your code in the same format as the first variation above, but with all your parentheses intact:

```c
{
        # too many ( below
        if ((
                (substr($0,9,3) == "TGO") &&
                (
                        # missing ) below, alt. too many ( and )
                        (substr($0,1,4) == "9123" || (substr($0,1,4) == "9704")
                )
        )
                print (substr($0,279,2),substr($0,1,4),substr($0,5,8))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure since you haven't given us a file to test with, but I am guessing this is what you wanted to write:

```
awk '{ if( substr($0,9,3) == "TGO" && (substr($0,1,4) == "9123" || substr($0,1,4) == "9704")){ print substr($0,279,2),substr($0,1,4),substr($0,5,8)}}' Downloadfinance.txt
```

Or, a little more legibly:

```
awk '{ 
        if( substr($0,9,3) == "TGO" && 
            (substr($0,1,4) == "9123" || substr($0,1,4) == "9704")){ 
                print substr($0,279,2),substr($0,1,4),substr($0,5,8)
            }
    }' Downloadfinance.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can move `if` condition to the rule precondition:

```
awk  'substr($0,9,3) == "TGO"  && (substr($0,1,4) == "9123" || substr($0,1,4) == "9704"){
                print substr($0,279,2),substr($0,1,4),substr($0,5,8)
              }'
```

You can also simplify it to:

```
awk 'substr($0,9,3) == "TGO"  && (/^9123/ || /^9704/) { print .... }'
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you use *GNU* awk (or can) [it has a feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Constant-Size.html) to handle this directly:

```
awk -vFIELDWIDTHS="4 4 3 267 2" '$3=="TGO" && ($1=="9123"||$1=="9704"){ print $5,$1,$2 }'
```